# Multiplication in excel

Tags: worksheet-function

If I enter age in a cell it should calculate the no.of tabs to be given.
the range is ages 1-4 tablets2, ages 5-8 tablets3, ages 9-14 tablets 4, age 15 and above 5 tablets. How to create a formula based on this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Test the age in the **proper order**.  With age in **A1**:

```
=IF(A1<5,2,IF(A1<9,3,IF(A1<15,4,5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use MATCH:

```
=MATCH(A1,{1,5,9,15})+1
```